# Vertical space canonically isomorphic to fibre

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over $M$. Where the projection is $\pi:E \rightarrow M$. Let $V_v$ be the kernel of $\pi_{*,v}$, I'm not sure if the following is true: $V_v$ is canonically isomorphic to $E_{\pi(v)}$.

Comment: Could you define $H, V$ and $\pi$?

Comment: What means $E_{\pi(v)}$?

Comment: The fibre over $\pi(v)$. Sorry I edited a typo

Comment: Yes, that's true. The fibre over $\pi(v)$ is the vector space $W:=\pi^{-1}(\pi(v))$  and the kernel of $\pi_{*,v}$ is the tangent space $T_v W\simeq W$. I don't see how is this connected to the connection.

Comment: You are right. The question is so badly asked, the connection is totally superfluous. I will edit it again. In any case could you expand why ker $\pi_{*,v}$ is $T_vW$? I see it thinking in a local trivialisation but there might be a nicer argument. Thanks